# Show and hide custom layout in bottom on layout with scale up and scale down animation

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom layout which includes three buttons which in have included in layout at bottom i want to Show and hide custom layout on click in android bottom of layout with slide up and slide down an scaling animation in android.

Comment: What did you get so far? Any code to show us?

Comment: Thanks Fasteque for reply. I solved this by adding adding Two Xml files in animation like zoom_enter and zoom_exit. Thanks again